# Spartacus Multisite support

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am trying to add Multisite in my Spartacus application. I have two domain names (let's say abc.in and xyz.in). Whenever I hit abc.in it should redirect to abc.in/electronic-spa/en and while hitting xyz.in it should redirect to xyz.in/apparal/en.

How to achieve this using MultiSite configurations in Spartacus?

Comment: Have you seen https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/automatic-context-configuration/?

Comment: Yes. I refer to that link. But I didn't get a clear idea of how to do it with the different domain names and multiple sites. Kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: Kindly help me to do it for multiple sites with different domains.

Answer (score 0):

Multisite works with the following mechanism:

- Multiple sites (`BaseSite`) are setup in the commerce backend. Each site might have a custom product and content catalog, but it's quite flexible to mix and match it all together. Customer are using a variety of combinations to end up with the actual site/content that they need for a specific market.
- Almost all API endpoints have the `site.uid` as part of the url. The API therefor can easily understand which content to return.
- If the same storefront application (Spartacus in this case) should use a single API, the storefront actually must know the `site.uid`, so it can construct the right API endpoint. The storefront would normally not know this unless you hard-code it.
- The commerce platform comes with a capability to link the storefront URL to the basesite, by using so-called regular expressions. A basesite can have multiple regex to configure to which storefront url the base site belongs. This is a very old mechanism in the commerce backend, that has been used in the (java) `CmsSiteFilter`. In spartacus we cannot use this filter, but we're using a similar filter mechanism. The same regex patterns are used, to filter the site, but it's done client side.

What you'd need to do to get it working:

- use minimal 1905 version on the backend (otherwise the `/basesites` endpoint is not available)
- setup your local hosts file, to mimic domain based URLs locally
- setup the basesite regex (urlPatterns) so that it will match the actual domain URLs
- run your Spartacus app with the `--disable-host-check` flag, so that it will listen to any local domain.